# Why is the CreationTime the same as LastWriteTime xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin.forms, set

---

I tried to set the **Creation time**, **Last Write Time** and **Last Access Time** of a file in **Xamarin forms** (Android).
To do this I used this simple code:

```
File.SetCreationTime(path, DateTime);
File.SetLastWriteTime(path, DateTime);
File.SetLastAccessTime(path, DateTime);
```

But it sets the **Creation Time** the same as the **Last Write Time** and i got **no exception**.
What should i do to fix this problem? On Windows it works fine...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "If the file system implementation does not support a time stamp to indicate the time when the file was created then this method returns an implementation specific default value, typically the last-modified-time" - https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes#creationTime()

Comment: Windows and Android use different file systems.  And I don't believe there is any standard file system that all Android versions/devices use.  So relying on these file attributes is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @Jason do you know an alternative Filesystem for android? Only the File.SetCreationTime() does not work the others working fine - thats, why im wondering..

Comment: You can't control the file system being used by the device.  I think you just need to accept that this is not a reliable piece of data and find a different approach.